# Tomcat's catalina not getting started

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to start **tomcat** on **linux** and I am getting **LifecycleException** exception whose snippet is below:

```
Apr 2, 2014 8:33:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Apr 2, 2014 8:33:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 2, 2014 8:33:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 2, 2014 8:33:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 890 ms
Apr 2, 2014 8:33:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.naming.NamingContext.setExceptionOnFailedWrite(Z)V
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Apr 2, 2014 8:33:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6 ms
```

I am trying to start it using startup.sh.

One reason I could guess for this is that either Tomcat jar might not be proper OR duplicate jars of different versions might be creating this issue. I have checked the both but couldn't find any such thing.

Appreciated if somebody could help me.

Comment: Check whether catalina.jar is in TOMECAT_HOME/lib location?

Comment: Thanks @SaiGowthami yes it's there.

Comment: It might be corrupted. Replace it one by downloading a fresh copy of the jar and check once.

Comment: @SaiGowthami Yes I had tried this and the problem is narrowed down to couple of additional Jboss client jars which I am keeping in the same folder which is creating this issue when they are added to /tomcat/lib. However this is not the first time I have done this and everything is working fine in other environments. Need to check this.

Answer (score 0):

Have got the same problem and solved it by unsetting unnecessary (all in my case) projects from Tomcat - Advanced - Add java projects to Tomcat classpath